What's the meaning of ️ as used by an dream dearg?
Looking at photos of Identity and Language (Northern Ireland) Act 2022 I noticed a recurring flag, that looks like ️. I'm curious as to what it means and where it comes from.
Searching some key terms I am pretty sure this is related to An dream dearg (the red crowd), or at least they use it a lot. Their website features the symbol heavily but does not make any explicit reference to its meaning.
The Vicipéid article for dearg le fearg (red with anger) discusses the symbol:

Tá ‘an fuilghrúpa O’ ar an gcúigiú straoiseog is mó úsáid i measc na nGael ar Twitter. Ní cúrsaí fola ná leighis a bhíonn i gceist ag lucht labhartha na Gaeilge nuair a bhíonn an straoiseog seo in úsáid acu, ainneoin teideal oifigiúil na siombaile, ach ‘Dearg le Fearg’. Tá an ciorcal bán ar chúlra dearg tarraingthe ag lucht an fheachtais chucu féin mar shuaitheantas idirlín. Tá leaganacha eile den chomhartha, mar shampla, ‘an ciorcal mór dearg’ ⭕, ann freisin.

Roughly translated...

The 'bloodgroup O' is the fifth most used emoticon amongst the Irish [speakers?] on Twitter. It's not affairs of blood or health that the Irish speaking people are talking about when they are using this emoticon, notwithstanding the official title of the symbol, but 'Red with Anger'. The white circle is drawn on a red background by the campaigners as their own internet logo. There are other versions of the sign, for example, 'the big red circle' ⭕, also.

But this doesn't provide any information about it's meaning other than that it is not about blood type. And the source linked is a little more explicit:

Beidh áthas ar An Dream Dearg ó thuaidh go bhfuil ‘an fuilghrúpa O’ ?ar an gcúigiú straoiseog is mó úsáid i measc na nGael ar Twitter. Ní cúrsaí fola ná leighis a bhíonn i gceist ag lucht labhartha na Gaeilge nuair a bhíonn an straoiseog seo in úsáid acu, ainneoin teideal oifigiúil na siombaile, ach an feachtas ‘Dearg le Fearg’. Tá an ciorcal bán ar chúlra dearg tarraingthe ag lucht an fheachtais chucu féin mar shuaitheantas idirlín.

Roughly translated (kind of the same thing really)...

An Dream Dearg from the north will be happy that 'the bloodgroup O' is the fifth most used emoticon amongst the Irish [speakers?] on Twitter. It's not affairs of blood or health that the Irish speaking people are talking about when they are using this emoticon, notwithstanding the official title of the symbol, but 'Red with Anger'. The white circle is drawn on a red background by the campaigners as their own internet logo.

It is used by an dream dearg and dearg le fearg and it's not about blood type. I can't find anything concretely explaining why this symbol was chosen or what it means.
The fact that it's red seems to do with anger over the failure to keep the promises of comhaontú chill rímhinn with regards to the Irish language. But that's mostly inferrence and doesn't explain much further.
What is the origin and meaning of this flag?

DOn't know if this is an answer, so I'll leave it as a comment.  This reddit post claims "The circle on the flag is representative of the Fáinne (ring), this is a symbol worn by Irish speakers to indicate their use of the language." Don't know whether that means the joined community of Irish language speakers or has some more esoteric sense.

Coudl you provide translations of the Irish quotes (machine translations or your own are sufficient).

@quarague I'm not confident in rendering my own translation, and the machine translations I had looked at had some errors which seemed confusing. The summaries I gave are accurate, the main thing is neither text really says much.

Awww, fickle SE.Po close reasons.  Some questions concerning flags are OK but not this one apparently.

Welcome to Politics SE! I'm voting to leave this one closed, but figured I'd step in here to explain why: This question is likely best answered on another SE - namely History SE. @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica points out that some flag questions (such as 'who uses what flag under what conditions) are in-bounds here, but the history and symbolism feels like there's other experts better equipped to get you to understanding.

According to the Irish language activist Pádraig Ó Tiarnaigh, quoted in 2017,

The logo that is being shared represents An Fáinne – a circular symbol traditionally worn as a pin to show you speak, or are learning Irish.
In this case we used a red background to represent anger; anger at what has occurred in recent weeks in regards to funding cuts to Líofa, and also anger at the ongoing discrimination against Irish speakers here.

Líofa, which is a officially supported initiative in Northern Ireland for encouraging fluency in the language, also uses the ring symbol - in their case, a gold one.
The word "fáinne" (ring) refers both to the badges and to the original language societies formed from about 1916. The founders were dissatisfied with the language policies of Sinn Féin and encouraged a stronger line, for example by asking followers to speak only Irish when interacting with British officials. The name of the society is credited to one of its founders, Colm Ó Murchadha (1889-1939), and the idea of a physical ring emblem to his compatriot Tadhg Ó Scanaill (1883-1967). (See the latter's entry at ainm.ie, citing a 1922 article in the serial Iris an Fháinne.) In the original conception, a gold ring would be awarded to people who were able to use the language to a high standard.
Popularity of the rings, and the nature of organizations offering them, has ebbed and flowed; there have been several revivals of the idea. The Wikipedia page Fáinne has more detail.
